# preg_match basics question

Tags: php, regex

Got some trouble with my preg_match.
The code.

```
$text = "tel: 012 213 123. mobil: 0303 11234 \n address: street 14";
$regex_string = '/(tel|Tel|TEL)[\s|:]+(.+)[\.|\n]/';

preg_match($regex_string , $text, $match);
```

And I get this result in $match[2]

```
"012 213 123. mobil: 023 123 123"
```

First question.
I want the regex to stop at the .(dot) but it doesent.
Can someone explain to why it isnt?

Second question.
preg_match uses () to get their match.
Is it possible to skip the parentheses surrounding the different "Tel" and still get the same functionality?

Thnx all stackoverflow is great :D

Comment: You sure `@match[2]` isn't actually `"012 213 123. mobil: 0303 11234"`?

Comment: oh im sorry i added some text that been missed when i ripped this out of its context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
/tel(?:\s|:)+([^.]+)(?:\.|$)/i
```

`+` is a greedy quantifier, which means it'll match as many characters as possible.

To your second question: in this particular case you just need to use case-insensitive match (`i` flag). Generally, you could use `(?:...)` syntax, example of which you could see in the end match. Square brackets are used for character classes.

Comment: If this is a greedy quantifier problem, what's `[\.|\n]` matching?

Comment: ok... didnt know about the (?:...) syntax... very helpful thnx.
I guess I dont really grasp the character classes yet.

Comment: @Richard: end of line of line character?

Comment: @Yo-L: they're just groups of characters. any of the character would be matched as many times as quantifier allows.

Comment: Seems so easy when u all explain it.
Harder to get it right just reading a table of instructions.
ty again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to extract a phone number out of that line, and it's guaranteed to be 11 numbers, you could simply use this:

```
$text = 'tel: 012 213 123. mobil: 0303 11234';
$phone_number = substr(preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $text), 0, 11);`
```

With your example, `$phone_number` would be `0122131230`.

How this works is any non-digit is replaced with an empty string, removing it, and then the first 11 numbers are returned.

Comment: Helpful but its not gonna be a static nomber of digits.

Comment: @Yo-L: So is it going to be the same format but just a varying amount of numbers? eg, a phone number without an area code?

Answer (score 1):

No idea - your regex works for me (I get "012 213 123" in `$match[2]` with your code). The fact that the mobile phone differs between the two might indicate that it's not really the output of your code; check again.

Some other things - if you happen to have more dots in the line ("tel: xxx. phone: xxx. fax: xxx" for example), you will get bad results - use non-greedy operators ("get least chunk that matches" `.*?` instead of "get biggest chunk that matches" `.*`) or limit the repeated characters ("any number of non-periods" `[^.]*`). Also, you could spare yourself the trouble by making the regex case-insensitive (unless you really hate people typing "tEl").

Your other question: `(?:stuff)` will match "stuff" just like `(stuff)`, but will not capture it.

Useful link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I got it abit wrong posting the question but Silentghost got it right anyway :S

Got that page up in another tab :) Still abit hard to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have pipes in your character classes `[\.|\n]` and `[\s|:]`? Character classes (stuff in square brackets `[]`) are by definition like an OR relationship, so you don't need the pipe... unless you really are trying to match pipe `|`.

As for question #1, I'm not sure what's cusiong your problem, but usually this has to do with greedy quantifiers. The `(.+)` quantifier is greedy, so it matches as much as it can while still matching the entire pattern. Greedy quantifiers don't care what comes after them in the pattern. Since a period `.` matches any character other than new line characters, it can match a period, and so it does match a period. To make a quantifier non-greedy you can use a question mark `?`.

For your second question In RegEx uses parenthesis to group things and to store them. If you want to group `(tel|Tel|TEL)` but not store it in `$match` you can put a `?:` at after the open parenthesis:

```
(?:tel|Tel|TEL)
```

Comment: Yeah I got the pipe messed up in there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to match *only* the number, so you don't have to strip off the `tel:` and the dot?  Try this:

```
/tel[:\s]+\K[^.]+/i
```

The `i` makes it case-insensitive.

`[:\s]` matches a colon or whitespace (the `|` doesn't mean "or" in a character class, it just matches a `|`).

`[^.]+` matches one or more non-dots; it stops matching when it sees a dot or the end of the line, so you don't have to match the dot if you don't want it in the result.

Finally, `\K` means "forget about whatever you've matched so far and pretend the match really started here"--a little gem of a feature that's only available in Perl and PHP (that I know of).